# Qt - confused on QDialog choice on main

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qdialog, qtgui

I have the following Qt code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    ChoosingDialog cdlg;

    if(!startWin.exec())
    {
        // nothing chosen
        return 0;
    }

    if(cdlg.firstWindowSelected)
    {
        CFirstWindow win;
        win.show();

        return app.exec();
    }
    else
    {
        CSecondWindow win;
        win.show();

        return app.exec();
    }

}
```

this seems to work but it's giving me an error on "event dispatcher cleanup" in some asm line. I tried to trick a bit and I saw that the problem is related to the app.exec() calling.

Update:
if I add these lines to the ChoosingDialog (this is a simple blank class auto-generated by Qt Creator)

```
void ChoosingDialog ::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *)
{
    exit(1);
}
```

I receive no errors

Comment: I tried your code (with a fake ChoosingDialog, CFistWindow and CSecondWindow) and except that `startWin` should be `cdlg` I did not encounter any error. Can you provide the implementation of your widgets?

Comment: I haven't widgets, I have a QDialog class with nothing on it (default generated by Qt Creator) and two QMainWindows (but the error happens also if I don't build their objects)

Comment: Yes, startWin should be cdlg. The code seems fine.

Comment: @Johnny: Can you post the exact error?

Comment: Calling `exit()` does not sound like a proper solution. Something else is going on here. I'd suggest to track down the error (especially since its only a small piece of code) than to write a 'workaround'.

Comment: Here it is: http://nopaste.info/32ee580336.html

Comment: Are you `delete`ing any of your objects? Or are you trying to copy them?

Comment: I think I'm not, the destructor is totally empty.. I'm loading the glew32 library, could it be the problem?

Comment: Hm... Diffucult to tell. Normally I come accross these problems, when I delete an QObject from a slot instead of calling `deleteLater()`.

Comment: I'm sure I'm not manipulating QObjects anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using the "singleapplication" class before the QApplication.. and something went wrong on the shared memory lock.

As soon as I restarted my system the exception disappeared... bof.. do you believe in magic?